# Changing Images (as background) every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<div id="background">
     <img src="#" alt="Background Image" class="first"/>
     <img src="#" alt="Background Image" class="second"/>
</div>
```

I dont have a SRC added because it'll reduce the loading time of my page. [(demo)](http://MdLPhotography.nl)

**JQuery**

```
        var current = "first";
        window.setInterval(function() {
            if(current == "first") {
                $("#background .second").prop("src", getMessage());
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#background .second").animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 1000);
                    $("#background .first").animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 1000);
                },1000);
                current = "second";
            } else if (current == "second") {
                $("#background .first").prop("src", getMessage());
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#background .first").animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 1000);
                    $("#background .second").animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 1000);
                },1000);
                current = "first";
            }
            getMessage()
        }, 5000);
```

so I have an array with src links to my images, which are randomly chosen by `function getMessage()`and while a picture is shown, the other IMG tag will change SRC and wait a second or two to get that image loaded and after that it will show with a animate.

But the problem is now: He doesn't show the second picture when the first picture got opacity 0 and the second picture got opacity 1.. **Edit:** The problem is the black fade between picture's.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: its working for me in IE.....

Comment: Yes, it's working but there is a black fade. That is supposed to be the second picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use setTimeout to add a buffer. You don't need this. What happens when the user is on a really slow connection? Your 1000ms won't do it. The correct thing to do here would be to create a new elemenent of type img. And listen to the onloadimage event. When it has fired, you can show the image.

Here is an example of this:
[Load Image from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396390/load-image-from-javascript)

In addition to this you'll need some CSS:

```
#background > img {position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
```

Comment: I'll have look, makes more sence then what I have now, thanks!

Comment: I'd implement this, the current conditions of my host shows why I need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following styles and it should fix your problem:

```
#background > img {position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
```

Comment: So why have you remove this as the answer when it clearly fixed your original problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use attr() function instead of prop()
Or try another one:

```
$("#background .first").animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 1000, function(){
// after finished first animation
$("#background .second").animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend using CSS for the transition.  I made a JSfiddle -
http://jsfiddle.net/9GEAn/1/ and it's far more efficient than the way you wrote it (I would recommend preloading the images, even though I didn't in the demo).

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    current++;
    if (current>=backgrounds.length) { current=0;}
    if ($bg1.css("opacity")==1) {
        $bg2.css({
            "background-image":"url("+backgrounds[current]+")",
            "opacity":"1"});
        $bg1.css("opacity","0");
    }
    else {
        $bg1.css({
            "background-image":"url("+backgrounds[current]+")",
            "opacity":"1"});
        $bg2.css("opacity","0");
    }
}, 5000);
```