# Forcing certain JS files and images to load before anything else including JS files

Tags: javascript, image, load

Because my client's page has tons of Javascript, the image carousel I added on top for mobile version takes forever to render on smartphones. I want to load carousel images then carousel required files (jQuery, carousel JS files, carousell CSS files) before anything else including JS, CSS, etc.

Is it possible, and if so how to do it?

Comment: first on top of page..include Jquery and then carousel js file ,caraousell css and at the end of your include rest of your javascript files...

Comment: As long as my carousel images are not loaded first as well, this will not solve the problem.

Comment: post fiddle if possible,it will help us to understand better and to solve your problem

Comment: How about adding js files at the end of body tag?

Answer (score 6):

Try this way:
[Load Image from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396390/load-image-from-javascript)
if you can load the image first and then just use it anywhere, they will load as soon as the javascript loads and you have to put this javascript before everything else (as you asked)

And, to load JS first, you just need to put them as the first, for example:

**JQuery** *must* be loaded BEFORE **Bootstrap** otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a javascript method which checks all images whether they are loaded or not.

```
var preLoadImages = function (arr) {
    var newImages = [], // temparary variable containing loaded images
        loadedImagesCount = 0; // 
    var postAction = function () {};
    var arr = (typeof arr != "object") ? [arr] : arr; // if a single image is sent, convert it into array

    function imageLoadPost() {
        loadedImagesCount++;
        if (loadedImagesCount == arr.length) {
            postAction(newImages) // postAction method
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newImages[i] = new Image();
        newImages[i].src = arr[i];
        newImages[i].onload = function () { // call imageLoadPost when image is loaded
            imageLoadPost();
        }
        newImages[i].onerror = function () { // call imageLoadPost when error occurred because its also an success event which already checked whether mage is available or not
            imageLoadPost();
        }
    }
    return { //return blank object with done() method
        done: function (f) {
            postAction = f || postAction // user defined callback method to be called when all images are loaded
        }
    }
}

// image array contains all images which you want to preload - currently having sample images
var imgArr = ['http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_images/jsfiddle-logo-thumb.png', 'http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_images/jsfiddle-desktop-thumbnail-a.png'];
preLoadImages(imgArr).done(function (imgArr) {
    alert('all images loaded');
    // call your carousel here
})
```

In done method, you can create your carousel. You need to add this method in a file and put that in top of the stack where you load your javascript files.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/s64Bn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea:

1. load jQuery first. [ADDED]
2. don't include the js and css files you want to lazy load.
3. write a javascript array (in order) for the js and css you want to lazy load (see below).
4. in the html identify with attribute all the  you want to load later.(just use an arbitrary attr)

   ```
   <img src="_images/loadMeFirst.jpg" />

   <img src="_images/1x1.png" lazyLoad="_images/loadMeLater.jpg" />
   ```
5. on document complete, go through all lazyLoad images, re-assign src attr with lazyload src.
6. on dom ready, add an arbitrary window event listener, perhaps "LoadNextScript", which will inject the next  from the array.
7. at the end of each injected js file, add a line to raise the (arbitrary) "LoadNextScript" event. (Note: You can skip this functionality if you are ok with the scripts loading asynchronously, and just load them like the css files.)

   ```
   $(window).trigger( "LoadNextScript" );
   ```
8. on document complete, raise the first (arbitrary) "LoadNextScript" event.
9. on document complete, inject the css files from the css array.

JS:

```
window.lazyLoad = {
    jsNextIndex: 0,
    jsFiles: ["_js/file1.js", "_js/file2.js"],
    cssFiles: ["_css/file1.css", "_css/file2.css"],
    loadLazyImages: function () {
        $('img[lazyLoad]').each(function () {
            var $img = $(this);
            $img.attr('src', $img.attr('lazyLoad'));
        });
    },
    loadNextScript: function () {
        // must add
        // $(window).trigger( "LoadNextScript" );
        // at the end of each js file to be lazy loaded.
        var sScriptSrc = window.lazyLoad.jsFiles[window.lazyLoad.jsNextIndex] || false;
        if (sScriptSrc) {
            $('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + sScriptSrc + '" />').appendTo($('body'));
        }
        window.lazyLoad.jsNextIndex++;
    },
    loadAllCss: function () {
        var $head = $('head');
        for (var i = 0; i < window.lazyLoad.cssFiles.length; i++) {
            $('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + window.lazyLoad.cssFiles[i] + '" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
        }
    },
    domReady: function () {
        // wire Lazy Script Event
        $(window).bind('LoadNextScript', window.lazyLoad.loadNextScript);

        // on window load complete (all non-lazy images)
        $(window).load(function () {
            // load all lazy images
            window.lazyLoad.loadLazyImages();
            // load the css
            window.lazyLoad.loadAllCss();
            // load/trigger the first script
            window.lazyLoad.loadNextScript();
        });
    }
};

jQuery(function ($) {
    // init lazy loader
    window.lazyLoad.domReady();
});
```

Comment: You only need to add the 'LoadNextScript' functionality if you need them to load in order.  Otherwise, exclude that and the scripts will run async.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<script async="true" src="zyx.js" />` and move your JS to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are having to work around the fact that your clients JS is loaded first without [implementing](https://github.com/cujojs/curl) a [more](http://requirejs.org/) [elegant](http://browserify.org/) [solution](http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/30/your-javascript-goes-where/) - you could always go for the simple solution and add the `async` attribute to the slow script.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesgorrie/SkdHf/1/)

If you are not able to do that - it would be good to know your limitations due to the existing code base (can you move the `script` tag for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an ajax load of all your images in carousel then consider using
`$.post` which is `async` in nature.