# changing the src of a children element

Tags: javascript, dom

I have three buttons and each one has an image with an empty `src`. I'm trying to randomly change the image `src` when clicking each button and if I'm seeing this correctly the console tells me that the image is being generated when I click but I can't seem to have it shown on the browser and I don't really get why.

```js
const images = 
    ["https://i.picsum.photos/id/102/60/60.jpg","https://i.picsum.photos/id/1024/60/60.jpg", 
     "https://i.picsum.photos/id/1062/60/60.jpg","https://i.picsum.photos/id/1069/60/60.jpg"];

  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

       buttons.forEach(function(el){  el.addEventListener("click", card);   })

       function card(){
           let random = Math.floor( Math.random() * 9);
           let image = this.children;
               console.log(image);
           image.src = images[random];
               console.log(image.src);    }
```

```html
  <div>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>      
   </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load Image from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396390/load-image-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
let image = this.children
```

The `this.children` refers to a collection of dom elements, not a single element; so you need to specify the first one in your case.

If there are multiple child nodes besides the image, you may wish to consider using `querySelector('img')` instead.

```js
const images = 
    ["https://i.picsum.photos/id/102/60/60.jpg",
    "https://i.picsum.photos/id/1024/60/60.jpg",
    "https://i.picsum.photos/id/1062/60/60.jpg",
    "https://i.picsum.photos/id/1069/60/60.jpg"];

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

buttons.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", card))

function card() {
  const randomImageUrl = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  const image = this.children[0];
  image.src = randomImageUrl;
  console.log(image.src);
}
```

```html
<div>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>      
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
this.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(function(img) { img.src = images[random] });
```

this will loop through all of the children.

Answer (score 0):

this.children returns an array.  You need to specify [0] to get the first one (only).

```js
const images = 
    ["https://i.picsum.photos/id/102/60/60.jpg","https://i.picsum.photos/id/1024/60/60.jpg", 
     "https://i.picsum.photos/id/1062/60/60.jpg","https://i.picsum.photos/id/1069/60/60.jpg"];

  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

       buttons.forEach(function(el){  el.addEventListener("click", card);   })

       function card(){
           let random = Math.floor( Math.random() * 9);
           let image = this.children;
               console.log(image);
           image.src = images[random];
               console.log(image.src);    }
```

```html
  <div>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>      
   </div>
```

```js
const images = 
    ["https://i.picsum.photos/id/102/60/60.jpg","https://i.picsum.photos/id/1024/60/60.jpg", 
     "https://i.picsum.photos/id/1062/60/60.jpg","https://i.picsum.photos/id/1069/60/60.jpg"];

  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

       buttons.forEach(function(el){  el.addEventListener("click", card);   })

       function card(){
           let random = Math.floor( Math.random() * 4);
           console.log(this.children);
           let image = this.children[0];
               console.log(image);
           image.src = images[random];
               console.log(image.src);    }
```

```html
<div>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>      
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems:

1. `children` is plural, but when you intend to change the `src` of an image, then it needs to be singular. children is array-like-object, while image is an element. No problem, children is an array-like-object which contains elements.
2. You have 4 elements, but you randomize 9. You need to be consistent with your upper limits.

Working code:

```
<div>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>
       <button type="button"><img src="" alt=""></button>      
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
const images = 
    ["https://i.picsum.photos/id/102/60/60.jpg","https://i.picsum.photos/id/1024/60/60.jpg", 
     "https://i.picsum.photos/id/1062/60/60.jpg","https://i.picsum.photos/id/1069/60/60.jpg"];

  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

       buttons.forEach(function(el){  el.addEventListener("click", card);   })

       function card(){
           let random = Math.floor( Math.random() * 4);
           let image = this.children[0];
               console.log(image);
           image.src = images[parseInt(random)];
               console.log(image.src);    }
</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p5hyvdzo/